# How to download all the raw emails using some email client?

Tags: email, email-client

Can I download all the emails **and have them saved in raw format (headers and such)** using some email client such as Thunderbird, Outlook, etc?

Comment: .. from where are you downloading them? And what is raw format?

Comment: Raw format is like the original email with all the headers, etc. From where? -      does it matter?

Comment: They are already saved in "raw format". You need to ask your email client to display all headers. For example, [Displaying Full Message Headers in Microsoft Outlook (Windows)](http://its.yale.edu/how-to/article-displaying-full-message-headers-microsoft-outlook-windows) and [How to View Complete Message Headers in Mozilla Thunderbird](http://email.about.com/od/mozillathunderbirdtips/qt/How-to-View-Complete-Message-Headers-in-Mozilla-Thunderbird.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, most of the popular email clients *already do that*.

Although I wouldn't recommend Outlook, as it does deform the headers a bit – Thunderbird works better in that regard. (You can even drag & drop a message from Thunderbird to your desktop, and have it stored as a regular file.)

On Linux you could also use Claws, `mutt`, OfflineIMAP, or any of the dozens of IMAP clients.

Comment: Can I drag them **all** and have them saved as plaintext?

Comment: Probably? Never tried. The internal storage format that Thunderbird uses is also plaintext (Maildir in latest version, mbox in earlier ones).

Comment: Okay. I only worked with exporting into those backup formats so far.

Comment: Well, drag & drop doesn't work, but "Save as" and choosing the destination will save it in .eml, which is plaintext (obviously, since Thunderbird  stores them in plaintext)

Comment: There's nothing "obvious" in the latter part. For all you know, the mail client could store the messages in a database (e.g. Outlook uses .pst, Geary uses sqlite) and extract the plaintext on demand. I only mentioned the plaintext thing because you might have wanted to access the stored mails _directly_, from within Thunderbird's profile folder.

Comment: Right, I just, well, you said "The internal storage format that Thunderbird uses is also plaintext "

Comment: @grawity, I see that thunderbird collapses double spaces in your Subject header when sending mails. Also, when reading mails it auto capitalizes the word `re:` and adds a space after it. Do you know of any good raw email clients that does not automatically transform my mails?